# Static and synchronized in a Java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, static

While programming my web calendar, I have to think about using static methods or not. 
There is an abstract class Serializer, that saves and load content in particular files. 
Should I synchronized both methods load and save, if they are static?

Another option would be to define both methods as dynamic class content, the class would be not abstract and if I want to save or load data, I am using an instance of Serializer.

Thank you for answers. :)

Comment: You need to write thread-safe code.  Good luck.

Comment: And another method would to send the files to the Serializer asynchronously and let him queue them to Serialize.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the case where more than one process may be accessing the file, you should use a lock on the file (see [FileChannel.lock]).[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29) Or better, use a proper database.

Comment: Ok, I look that I use a database. Would it better to write a singleton object that has as only object access to database? I think yes..

Comment: Singleton only adds complication to a `static`. Mutable statics are usually a bad idea. It's much better just to create an object once, passing it through constructors. / But still, locking a file is the preferred way to lock a file.